# How to find new type in typedef

Tags: c++, c, typedef

There are tons of tutorials on how to read typedefs, especially for function pointers. The left-right-rule always starts with "find the newly defined type, then ...". I understand the "then..." part, but not how to find the new type.

I know this is "intuition", but I wanted to have a clear recipe that a computer can understand.

My first idea: The new type is the first type you encounter that is not yet defined. True for function pointers:

```
typedef char (*(*x[3])(int y))[5];
```

Here, x is the first undefined identifier, so x is the new type. Now, look at this:

```
typedef struct { int y; } x;
typedef union { int y; } x;
typedef enum { y } x;
```

The rule does not apply here: y is the first unknown identifier, but x is the typedefed type.

Is there a rule to find the new typedefed type in all possible typedefs?

Comment: In your three latter examples, the name "y" is not "not yet defined" or "unknown" - it is defined by respectively the struct, union, and enum where it occurs. (You can't subdivide `enum { y }`.) The examples have the same structure as `typedef int x;`.

Comment: Try "first undefined identifier outside of curly braces".

Comment: If you remove the `tyoedef` keyword, what's left is a variable declaration. The name of the typedef is the name of the variable. I'm not posting this as an answer because parsing variable declarations is still non-trivial. Incidentally, `typedef` does not create a new type, just a new name for an existing type.

Comment: @n.m. or "first undefined identifier outside of curly braces that isn't a `struct`/`union`/`enum` tag".

Comment: To expand on my previous comment, `typedef` is treated syntactically like a storage class specifier, like `extern`, `static`, or `register`.  Logically it's a very different thing (it creates a new name for a type rather than declaring an object). The syntactic similarity is purely for convenience.

Comment: @Keith Thompson nailed it.  The "type alias" that is being defined is the identifier that would be declared a variable without the typedef keyword.  If you are considering a program that would automatically identify this identifier, such a program will have to have the smarts to properly parse the entire syntax.  Simple heuristics will not do.

Comment: K&R C book devotes some space to describing how to write a parser for declarations. I do not remember how exhaustive it was, but it's certainly worth looking into.

Comment: @PiotrNycz: It's only similar if you consider every question similar that has questions about types in C.

Comment: How about finding the 'first undefined identifier' in `typedef struct xx { int yy; } zz;` — is it `xx` or `zz`?

Comment: @CiaPan: xx in this expression is declared as a struct (definition following immediately) and thus not undefined/unknown any more. Thus remains zz...

Answer (score 0):

Well, your y actually **are** defined: In your first two examples *y* is a member variable of type int within the anonymous struct/union and as such well defined. In the third example, *y* is one of the enum members and again well defined. For better understanding, imagine your typedefs would have been written as:

```
struct _x { int y; };
typedef struct _x x;

union _x { int y; }
typedef union _x x;

enum _x { y };
typedef enum _x x;
```

(C++ allows simplifying this to `typedef _x x;` in all three cases, C does not, however...)

From point of view of the typedef, it's exactly the same. The only true difference is that now the typedef'ed types have names (_x)...

Comment: Unless you are in some C dialect, where `struct _x { int y; }; typedef _x x;` resolves to a compile time error because you need `struct _x { int y; }; typedef struct _x x;`. Long story short: beware of trivial answers.

Comment: Absolutely true - missed that the question is tagged 'C', too... Edited the answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Every type exists of a non-pointer type followed by zero or more qualifiers, where the qualifiers can be *, &, const, volatile and/or restrict. It is after those qualifiers that the new typename appears in a typedef. This changes the question to 'where do those qualifier appear',
because they don't really appear at the end of the characters that make up the base-type, but can appear somewhere 'in the middle' when the base type is an array and/or (member)function.

For example:

```
typedef int array[5]; // new type 'array' of type int[5].
typedef int* array[5]; // new type 'array' of type int*[5];
typedef int (*array)[5]; // new type 'array' of type pointer-to-int[5].
typedef int function(float); // new type 'function' of type int ()(float)
typedef int (*function)(float); // new type 'function' of type int (*)(float) or pointer-to int ()(float).
typedef int (Class::*member)(float); // new type 'member' of type member-function-pointer to int (Class::)(float).
```

These are the only types where the qualifiers appear in the middle, the rest has the form:

```
typedef SOMETYPE<qualifiers here> newtype_here;
```

These constructions would still be rather easy to parse if it wasn't for the fact that they can also be combined. Aka:

An array:

```
TYPE name [DIM]
```

A function pointer:

```
RETTYPE (*name) (PARAMS)
```

An array of function pointers:

```
RETTYPE (*name[DIM]) (PARAMS)
```

A function returning a pointer to an array:

```
TYPE (*name(PARAMS)) [DIM]
```

A pointer to a function(1) returning a reference to an array of const function(2) pointers:

```
RETTYPE (* const (&(*name)(PARAMS2))[DIM])(PARAMS1)
```

So, if you can eliminate all brackets with PARAMS which can be recognized by the fact that they start with a known type (ie: (int ...)), then the new type will either appear all the way on the right or inside the inner most pair of brackets (that aren't function (PARAMS)) after one or more qualifiers.

Lets construct the type above in steps:

A pointer to
- a function(2) returning
-   a reference to
-     an array of
-       a const
-         pointer to
-           a function(1)

Now read it backwards:

a function(1):

```
RETTYPE ( )(PARAMS1)
         ^
```

pointer to:

```
RETYPE (* )(PARAMS1)
         ^
```

(being) const:

```
RETTYPE (* const )(PARAMS1)
                ^
```

an array of:

```
RETTYPE (* const ( )[DIM])(PARAMS1)
                  ^
```

a reference to:

```
RETTYPE (* const (& )[DIM])(PARAMS1)
                   ^
```

a function(2) returning:

```
RETTYPE (* const (& ( )(PARAMS2))[DIM])(PARAMS1)
                     ^
```

a pointer to:

```
RETTYPE (* const (& (* )(PARAMS2))[DIM])(PARAMS1)
                      ^
```

then the new type-name will be put where the ^ points to.

Comment: Your answer is not referencing my question. From what you say, the type specifier (plus the stuff behind) introduce the typedef'd type. That's not true for the struct in my examples: `typedef struct { int y; } x;` : The first time that a type specifier is fully mentioned (reading from left to right) is after the `int` (the struct is not yet completely defined). So from your answer, `y` would have been typedef'd.

Comment: I said that only arrays, functions and member functions have a pre- and postfix (the qualifiers and new type appear in the middle). Since a struct is neither, the new type appears at the end. The syntax is: `typedef struct { ... } newtype;` and it doesn't matter what is between the `{ ... }`. [PS I'm the author of the first (new ABI) C++ demangler that demangled 100% correctly ;). A demangler outputs types; so I know pretty sure the construction of a type as I showed at the bottom is the right way to think about this.]

Comment: Have you noticed? Although the type is not yet complete, the first unknown identifier still is 'array' (would correspond to the 'x' in the question) in all the examples. So Johannes intuition would still apply here, too (well, at least, if reading the question as 'find the name of...', which is what i did intuitively). At a first glance, this seems to be conflicting with the struct/union/enum case, (int array <-> int y), however the important difference is that we are right within a type definition which has to be completed before considering the 'first unknown' rule...

Comment: @CarloWood: Let's see if I can follow: A struct is none of array/function/member function (function pointers probably need to be mentioned, too), so it has no prefix. Since it has no prefix, the last thing can not be a prefix, so it must be the newly defined type. Is that what you meant? Btw: Sorry if my answer sounded unfriendly, but if my question is mostly about structs, those should clearly be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Johannes: I'd say 'postfix' instead of prefix. But, to summarize: each typedef begins with a (known) type followed by either the new type, or by a series of opening brackets and/or qualifiers and then the new type; optionally followed by closing brackets and/or (PARAMS) and/or [DIM] sequences.

Comment: All in all not too hard to decipher thus, if it wasn't for the fact that both the first type as well as the PARAMS list can be arbitrarily complex and therefore might make it hard to decipher where they end. In the case that the leading type is a struct, then I wouldn't call it very complex as the {..} are neatly balanced and thus it's easy to find where the struct ends. Ie: `typedef struct foo { int (*f)(int); int y } (* const name)(struct foo&);` clearly has as return type `struct foo {...}` and thus 'name' is the new type.